# How to make full-paged Table's Caption full-paged

Tags: tables, capitalization, fullpage

My Table can show in full-paged mode.

But my caption still at half-paged mode.

I want my caption be centering in page.

How to solve this issue?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}  % load the afterpage package
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\resizebox` macro
\usepackage[margin=0.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption

\begin{document}

\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering, singlelinecheck=off}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Average & STD & Z & P \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{\label{table2} TRADITIONAL EVALUATION SCALE STATISTICAL RESULTS}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a compilable code, that reproduces this behaviour. We don't even know the document class in use.

Comment: Welcome Harry, you just need `\begin{table*}[ht] ... \end{table*}`

Comment: Thanks to mention me about that. I have updated my code and make sure it could compilable.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks a lot! I follow your advice and solved this issue.